# Oracle SQL convert date format from DD-Mon-YY to YYYYMM

Tags: sql, oracle, date-format, to-date

I have a to compare dates in 2 tables but the problem is that one table has the date in DD-Mon-YY format and the other in YYYYMM format.

I need to make both of them YYYYMM for the comparison.

I need to create something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM offers 
WHERE offer_date = (SELECT to_date(create_date, 'YYYYMM') FROM customers where id = '12345678') 
AND offer_rate > 0
```

where create_date is something like 12-Mar-2006 and offer_date is something like 200605

Any ideas where I need to adapt this query??

Comment: Why are you having a problem? Is offer_date a `VARCHAR2` (string)?

Comment: Dates don't have formats like that. If you want that format, you want a string by definition. So, are you looking for strings (with that format) or DATETIMEs (which doesn't have a format).  And so, if your fields "have different formats", what are their actual data types? DATETIMEs, a VHARCHAR()s, etc?

Comment: @phil - offer_date is a NUMBER field

Comment: @Dems - in addition to the above comment, create_date is a DATE field

Comment: @Tom: It would better if you could convert the datatypes of those date columns to `DATE`. Why use `NUMBER` for a date column?

Comment: @ypercude - unfortunately I'm not in a position to make that kind of a change - I just have to muddle through with what I am given!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `offer_date` is an number, and is of lower accuracy than your real dates, this may work...
- Convert your real date to a string of format `YYYYMM`
- Conver that value to an INT
- Compare the result you your `offer_date`

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  offers
WHERE
    offer_date = (SELECT CAST(to_char(create_date, 'YYYYMM') AS INT) FROM customers where id = '12345678')
AND offer_rate > 0
```

Also, by doing all the manipulation on the `create_date` you only do the processing on one value.

Additionally, had you manipulated the `offer_date` you would not be able to utilise any index on that field, and so force SCANs instead of SEEKs.

Answer (score 1):

Am I missing something?  You can just convert offer_date in the comparison:

```
SELECT *
FROM offers
WHERE to_char(offer_date, 'YYYYMM') = (SELECT to_date(create_date, 'YYYYMM') FROM customers where id = '12345678') AND
      offer_rate > 0
```

Comment: I think you're somewhere near the solution. Would it help I was to say that create_date is DATE format and offer_date is NUMBER format (which really isn't all that helpful!)

Comment: `WHERE to_char(offer_date, 'YYYYMM') = (SELECT to_char(create_date, 'YYYYMM') FR...` did the tricks... thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @Tom : Do note; wrapping `offer_date` in `to_char()` will obfuscate any index on that field. Instead, you can do all the processing on the `create_date`, as you only need to do that once for this query, then make use of indexes for an index seek on `offer_date`. *[Doing manipulation on scalar constants in nearly infinitely preferable to manipulating the data being searched.]*