# SQL Date without time part displayed (really not displayed)

Tags: sql, oracle, date, time

I have a fairly simple problem that I cannot resolve... 
I need to display date without time (getting rid of time by still displaying 00:00:00 won't do in my case), so solutions like

```
select trunc(sysdate) from dual;

select TO_DATE('20160517','YYYYMMDD') from dual;
```

do not really solve my problem.

What is more, my Oracle does not support `covert()` or `dateadd(),datediff(),getdate()` functions. Any help appreciated!

Edit: the purpose of this is to concatenate the existing date with some hard code time.

Comment: ANSI SQL way is cast as date. Don't know if Oracle supports it though.

Comment: If push comes to shove you can always `substring` it

Comment: Generally, this problem is best solved on client.  What client system are you displaying the date in ?

Comment: Please see this link. I think it is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536626/oracle-sql-convert-date-format-from-dd-mon-yy-to-yyyymm

Comment: Why does not `trunc()` solve the problem? what result do you expect?

Comment: `select to_char(sysdate, 'yyyymmdd') from dual;`

Comment: @Aleksej select trunc(sysdate) from dual; still displays 17.05.2016 00:00:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want display some DATE field without time just use `TO_CHAR` function. For exmaple:

```
SELECT to_char(sysdate, 'DD.MM.YYYY')
  FROM dual
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @hinotf! I've figured out I could do something like this. It's not beautiful but at least Oracle does not complain about the wrong date format.

```
select to_date(to_char(sysdate , 'dd.mm.yyyy')||' 11:01:00') from dual;
```

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? Create a date at a specific time? I'd typically do something like: `select trunc(sysdate) + 11/24 + 1/(24*60) from dual;` rather than converting to a string and then back to a date again.

Comment: You're relying on your NLS settings when converting back to a date. You should at least do `to_date(to_char(sysdate , 'dd.mm.yyyy')||' 11:01:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')`. But there are other ways to manipulate the time, depending on where the `11:01:00` part is actually coming from.

Comment: Hi @AlexPoole, thanks for your answer. Could you be so kind and explain what is the risk of not specifying 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ? Thank you!

Comment: The risk is you run it in a session which has a different NLS_DATE_FORMAT and the `to_date()` fails because the string you've constructed doesn't match that format. (Or potentially works but gets the wrong value, if MM and DD and swapped, though that fails too with high day numbers). Avoid relying on NLS settings - don't make assumptions about the session that will run the code. You can get odd side effects too.